# how to tell Lua to click on "loading button" infinitely?

Tags: web-scraping, lua, scrapy-splash

This is the first time I'm using splash to scrape a website. I need to tell splash to click on a button so that the other elements get loaded on the browser. This goes on infinitely. Then I want the splash to return the HTML code, so that I can scrape it with my spider. The loading button doesn't have an href, so, I can't use pagination. Thus, I tried to write a splash script to do so. But as I run the script with splash it seems that the "btn" part doesn't play any role in the returned HTML (only the first page's HTML is returned every time.)

Here is the splash script I wrote:

```
function main(splash,args)

    local function wait_for(it)
        item=splash:select(it)
        while not item:visible() do
            splash:wait(0.25)
            item=splash:select(it)
            return item
        end 
    end 

    splash.private_mode_enabled=false
    local head={'User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome'}
    assert(splash:go(args.url,headers=head))

    selector='.undefined.btn.small-Font'
    wait_for(selector):mouse_click()

    selector='.rtl.custom-container.pb-5'
    wait_for(selector):mouse_click()

    return splash:html()

end
```

Can anybody help me understand how I can tell splash that "while the "loading button" exists, press it, then return the whole HTML at once"?

By the way, here is the non-English URL I want to scrape:
http://namlik.me/channels

Thank you so much!!

---EDIT---

This is the error I got on the response page:

```
{
    "error": 400,
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script",
    "info": {
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash,args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 14,
        "error": "')' expected near '='",
        "type": "LUA_INIT_ERROR",
        "message": "[string \"function main(splash,args)\r...\"]:14: ')' expected near '='"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't exist, wait a moment, and try again.  You can do the same with your container, instead of `splash:wait(10)`.
https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html#element-visible

```
btn = splash :select(".undefined.btn.small-Font")
visible = btn :visible()
while not visible do
    splash :wait( 0.25 )
    btn = splash :select(".undefined.btn.small-Font")
    visible = btn :visible()
end
btn :mouse_click()
```

---

---

That wait routine could be a function.

```
function main( splash, args )

    local function wait_for( it )
        item = splash :select( it )
        while not item :visible() do
            splash :wait( 0.25 )
            item = splash :select( it )
        end  --  visible?
        return item
    end  --  wait_for()

    splash .private_mode_enabled = false
    local head = { 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome' }
    splash :set_user_agent( head )
    assert(  splash :go( args .url )  )

    selector = '.undefined.btn.small-Font'
    wait_for( selector ) :mouse_click()

    selector = '.rtl.custom-container.pb-5'
    wait_for( selector ) :mouse_click()

    return splash :html()

end  --  main()
```

Comment: Thank you, @Doyousketch2 for your explanation. I replaced the "btn" part with your code and run splash. It worked without any errors. But again, on the response page, I got the HTML of the first page of the website. Shouldn't it show the whole HTML file? or it always shows the first page? By the way, the "html: String (length 44838)" is the same as before.

Comment: Don't know enough about that webpage to tell you why it would be.  Maybe pages require cookies to navigate.  You might try removing curly-bracket in your return statement `return splash:html()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Doyousketch2. I edited the above post, and in the "EDIT" part put the error I got. I also changed the splash script as you said. I know it may seem foolish but I didn't find any debugger for errors I get and others' similar questions weren't helpful for this error. So, I put it here. Thank you again.